# how to access google calendar API methods

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I am new to Google APIs and am trying to create an app based on the Google Calendar API sample  described here: http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-appengine-sample/instructions.html.

This works, but I am having trouble going further, because I can't access all the API methods, like get, patch, list, etc that are described at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/.

There are a few methods implemented in the sample app source code: /year-planner/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/calendar/appengine/server/CalendarGwtRpcSample.java:

```
void delete(GwtCalendar calendar) throws IOException;
GwtCalendar insert(GwtCalendar calendar) throws IOException;
GwtCalendar get(GwtCalendar calendar) throws IOException;
GwtCalendar update(GwtCalendar updated) throws IOException;
```

But only delete, insert and update methods are implemented.  I expected that these would be available directly from the client library.

Have I missed something? or do I need to create all these methods myself?

I've followed the tutorial for the sample app, using Eclipse on Windows (Vista) with source code and client libraries from Maven repositories.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to write wrappers for all the service calls you want - the reason being you can't use Ajax to call out to a web service (the google calendar API in this case) on a different server to the one hosting your GWT application.

So in this example case your GWT application makes an AJAX call to your server, which then calls out to the Google Calendar service and wraps the result back to the GWT client.